# Script (PHP & Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Need help with following script. It shows only "Resource id #5" in php.

```
$some_q = "SELECT SUM(Bank) AS 'count_bank' FROM players";

$results = mysql_query($some_q);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

echo $row['count_bank'];

}
```

Comment: try mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: not clear, what result you are expecting

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated, use `mysqli`.

Comment: Do not use any mysql_-function. It's deprecated. The new way is with mysqli_ functions. They work the same way but they are much newer and better. This should help you: http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

Try with mysql_fetch_assoc

```
mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
```

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. **The type of returned array depends on
>   how result_type is defined.** By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get
>   an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC,
>   you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), **[by] using
>   MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works)**.

```
mysql_fetch_row ( resource $result )
```

> Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched
>   row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.
>
> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated
>   with the specified result identifier. **The row is returned as an array.
>   Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.**